# Shell script arrays

Tags: linux, arrays, bash, loops

I would like to set array elements with loop:

```
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
do
array[$i] = 'sg'
done

echo $array[0]
echo $array[1]
```

So it does not work.
How to..?

Comment: Do you know the seq command? you could replace your numbers with $(seq 0 9)

Comment: You need to be careful, as some shells do not have arrays.  If you want to writable portable sh, you cannot use arrays at all.

Comment: Definitely a bashism, I've fixed the tags.

Answer (score 7):

Remove the spaces:

```
array[$i]='sg'
```

Also, you should access the elements as<sup>*</sup>:

```
echo ${array[0]}
```

See e.g. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html.

---

<sub>* Thanks to @Mat for reminding me of this!</sub>

Answer (score 2):

It should work if you had declared your variable as array, and print it properly:

```
declare -a array
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
do
    array[$i]="sg"
done
echo ${array[0]} 
echo ${array[1]}
```

See it in action [here](http://ideone.com/aDy5y).

HTH

Answer (score 1):

there is problem with your echo statement: give `${array[0]}` and `${array[1]}`

Answer (score 1):

```
# Declare Array

NAMEOFSEARCHENGINE=( Google Yahoo Bing Blekko Rediff )

# get length of an array
arrayLength=${#NAMEOFSEARCHENGINE[@]}

# use for loop read all name of search engine
for (( i=0; i<${arrayLength}; i++ ));
do
  echo ${NAMEOFSEARCHENGINE[$i]}
done
```

**Output:**

Google
 
Yahoo
Bing 
Blekko 
Rediff

Answer (score 0):

My take on that loop:

```
array=( $(yes sg | head -n10) )
```

Or even simpler:

```
array=( sg sg sg sg sg sg sg sg sg sg )
```

See **http://ideone.com/DsQOZ** for some proof. Note also, bash 4+ readarray:

```
readarray array -t -n 10 < <(yes "whole lines in array" | head -n 10)
```

In fact, readarray is most versatile, e.g. get the top 10 PIDs of processes with bash in the name into array (which could return an array size<10 if there aren't 10 such processes):

```
readarray array -t -n 10 < <(pgrep -f bash)
```

Comment: added readarray, which has it's place for allowing embedded whitespace easily